# How to write with pyautogui letters like ěščřžý with UTF-8, but i cannot use ctrl + v

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to use letters like ěšřýáí with pyautogui.write or typewrite but pyautogui.write doesn't using UTF-8 and i cannot use ctrl + v.

```
if(vyberpapir == "402"):
                txtopen = io.open("cctyrdva.txt", encoding="utf-8")

                vysledek = txtopen.read()
                print(vysledek)

                input("Po stisknutí enteru máš 5 sekund na přepnutí do zavu na cvičení. Pro pokračování zmáčkni enter: ")
                tm.sleep(5)
                pa.write(vysledek, interval=0.05)
```

Comment: What's the problem? Python 3 strings are already Unicode. That means that `vysledek` is Unicode and `pyautogui.write` *does* support Unicode, simply because it accepts a string. Windows is a Unicode operating system too. So is this page. If the file contents are really UTF8 there shouldn't be any problem

Comment: I suspect the real problem is that `write` emulates the keyboard instead of sending text. In that case you should find a better library. Windows and MacOS allow manipulating and reading UI elements directly through accessibility APIs. These APIs are also used to automate GUI applications. This is far more than moving the button around and sending keyboard events. On Windows consider using eg [pywinauto](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto)

Comment: The text that is written by **write**  have to be like that I'm writting that now. @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: Then use a different library. Windows allows sending text to controls. That's how all accessibility, automation and RPA tools work. They don't depend on sending keyboard events like `write` does.

Comment: Another option is to send the keyboard events that switch languages and then send the *keyboard letters* instead of the actual characters. That's not a UTF8 issue though